# Run two functions simultaneously without using pthread or other similar libraries

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I want to run two functions simultaneously in C without using pthread or other libraries. Delays in any function shouldn't affect the execution of the other.

```
void func1(){
     /*do something*/
}

void func2(){
     /*do something*/
}
```

How would I do that? Can anybody provide a good algo.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to run functions truly simultaneously without using multiple threads. However you can simulate concurrent execution with [coroutines](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html).

If there is no platform restrictions it is better to use multithreading. It is simple to use pthreads or OpenMP especially if functions are independent and there is no data races.